# Let type be inferred instead of explicitly typing it

Tags: typescript

I have a base class Connector that is being extended by a number of sub classes:

```
export class SpecificConnector1 extends Connector
export class SpecificConnector2 extends Connector
...
```

Now I have a little TypeScript problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

Consider this example on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7RBTYAXeAnaBvAUNEdGBgJYBuY6KAFAJR6HEtYroCuWi0ARAKy9mRAL74x+UJBgBlAA5oyAMzLAEyNJiwBGaCgAeNRABMY61BmxMWx+DPgBbdgAsyiAObzFK4NobWWYjZObj4IBWBlVSEWMQkpKGgvSJ9zTWwAJj1DFBMzJAstAKJbeyd0Vw9kqN9-AkCg9i4eXnDvaOFoOPx8JQ5EciRoNzJ0MjAQMgAvFDTLLAgAHgAVbKNTOAL0rAA+WiUALmh-AF4d6GX6I9X64mAkCHRoe4156BPoJQZO4Obnrfm4h6kgeTxeug+IzGE2mswBWiW1VS8Ow2j2p3OqAA7kkIjU5lptPQQYhHv9EFlIYhRuNJjMCdhEXjka8tBl0YwztBsbj2moUVgMsTev1BjwXoVsAAJMAmEAoLC0CXbCBHADaDKwABpuRwHAAjBUAXTVRsYtyIAHpLdAQPB3KpoBVqNBftwYMrAawmqFPQi1QAGI1A-DW6AAUX0YAccnl0G0oZt8qe6AAngpoIbhoglAq2MYSWS-YyIdA1Z01eCdUGtRWXhkdQBmYPBxNOmB57AkyVYGVyhVKgUQIk9MOR6OxlDQDKFsFDjLqzU6xB6w1YE1G95lutIbTVo21liVpAN6DN-CtsOIeDtvRYLBWLGuYDOaAOMAAaxQMAguV-3e2PtjHlRViwWIVRxtABFDhvzGJAjjIGBRmgOR4CgMh9TjTBuXgJ5nDACgpxwgxY1UUYQFTJ10ynMDhxIEwnWcBUUCUKx3y-CMoxjONdCxbAPxIZCniQgB+IA):

```js
class Connector {
    activate() {
        return "5"
    }
}

class SpecificConnector1 extends Connector {
    doSomethingSpecific1() {
        return "specific"
    }
}

class SpecificConnector2 extends Connector {
    doSomethingSpecific1() {
        return "specific"
    }
}

function initializeConnectors<T extends Connector>(f: () => T): T {
    const connector = f()
    return connector
}


const con1 = initializeConnectors<SpecificConnector1>(() => new SpecificConnector1)
const con2 = initializeConnectors<SpecificConnector2>(() => new SpecificConnector2)

function connectorHandler(connectors: [Connector, number][]) {
    // logic that returns connector
    return connectors[0]
}

// Example 1
// let type be inferred
const connectors1 = [
    [con1, 0],
    [con2, 3]
]

// ts error
connectorHandler(connectors1)

// Example 2
const connectors2: [Connector, number][] = [
    [con1, 0],
    [con2, 3]
]

// no ts error which makes sense
connectorHandler(connectors2)
```

My question is if it's possible to not have to explicitly type connectors1 and therefore make Example 1 work as it is?

Comment: Using `as const` and then changing it to `readonly [Connector, number][]` is one solution.

Comment: @kellys what do you mean exactly? something like this?

function connectorHandler(connectors: readonly [Connector, number][]) {
    // logic that returns connector
    return connectors[0]
}

// Example 1
// let type be inferred
const connectors1 = [
    [con1, 0],
    [con2, 3]
] as const

Comment: Exactly! It should work fine now.